# Spring - annotating the same class with both @Service and @Repository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

From time to time I find Spring components annotated with both @Service and @Repository. Something like this:

```
@Service("carService")
@Repository
@Transactional
public class CarServiceImpl implements CarService {
    ...
}
```

Or something like this:

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class EventService {

    @Autowired
    private EventRepository repository;

    public EventEntity save(final EventEntity entity) {
        return repository.save(entity);
    }

    public EventEntity findOne(final String idEvent) {
        return repository.findOne(idEvent);
    }
}
```

It seems convenient to do something like this, but is it technically correct implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Both `@Service` and `@Repository` are meta-annotated with `@Component`, which makes them eligible for scanning. As of Spring 5.0, `@Service` adds no further logic, while `@Repository` can add exception translation to the Spring DAO exception set if enabled.

However, it's also worth noting that in the example you provided, there's no advantage to having the `EventService` over simply having the Spring Data repository, and if there is additional logic, then it's not functioning as a repository (the `EventRepository` dependency is).

tl;dr: Use `@Component` or `@Service` on both, and there's no significant difference between them (`@Component` is becoming more usual because of that).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, `EventService` contains a lot of other things, I just removed them to improve readability.